# Can't add Google Account to OSX

Tags: macos, google

I can't set up my Google Accounts on my MacBook Pro. When adding my work (one step) or private (two-step) Google account in the internet accounts panel in system preferences, it doesn't go past this screen. When I select the apps to sync, I can click Done and then Done get's greyed out. I see the grey spinning wheel very shortly.
[image]

For the calendar, I tried this but without succes:
[Can't enable Gmail calendar syncing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121567/cant-enable-gmail-calendar-syncing)

I've had this issue on Yosemite as well, but now also for el Capitan. Other sites suggest going on a different network would solve the issue. I tried wired, WiFi and a mobile hotspot I created with my phone without succes.

It seems that in the process I'm going one step further than this guy [Internet Accounts - Login Issue with Google and iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212996/internet-accounts-login-issue-with-google-and-icloud). I'm running out of options and frustration is growing strongly. Thinking about doing a clean install.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was plaguing me for a long-time and was really annoying.

I initially thought it was an issue with a random plist or other file hanging out in the Library/ folder and I tried deleting many of them to try and get to the bottom of this.

Eventually, I was tipped off to a Keychain issue by looking in Console, which with some Google'ing, led me to [this post on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7339161?start=0&tstart=0).

Ultimately, I removed all of the following items in Keychain Access, retried adding the account in Internet Accounts, and everything worked well!

[image: Keychain Access items to remove]

It sounds like it was only the com.apple.account.Google.oauth* tokens that had to be removed, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling my Mac, which was overdue anyway. Still it was super frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods mentioned anywhere worked for me. However, I logged out of my iCloud account, added the Google accounts, then logged back into my iCloud. Everything worked after I logged out of iCloud and I got past the grey screen.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I also had to delete an entry called:[image]

name = "https://gmail.com"

Kind = Identity preferences

That did it for me.  I have too many saved credentials with "gmail.com" in them (my email), so searching 'gmail' isn't so easy.  Hopefully helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I went to add my google account and it asked me to authenticate in the browser and showed a small window with a loading spinner that would never load.

The solution for me was to change the default web browser to safari, system preferences > general > default web browser. Then try again and it worked. After this you can change your default browser back.